# Mat-tab-group header faster animate scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I have a row of tabs that are wider than their display width, the chevrons appear. I like that, but clicking them moves the tabs slowly and not to the next tab. Is there a config to control the scroll speed as well as a way to force the next tab into view?

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79cupm

Answer (score 1):

In your main.ts you have to add this to your imports:

`import { MAT_TABS_CONFIG } from '@angular/material/tabs';`

Then you can change the value of the InjectionToken by adding this to your provider array:

`{ provide: MAT_TABS_CONFIG, useValue: { animationDuration: 100 }}`

With this configuration the animation time will be 100ms

```js
import './polyfills';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {DemoMaterialModule} from './material-module';

import {TabGroupBasicExample} from './app/tab-group-basic-example';
import { MAT_TABS_CONFIG } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [TabGroupBasicExample],
  declarations: [TabGroupBasicExample],
  bootstrap: [TabGroupBasicExample],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_TABS_CONFIG, useValue: { animationDuration: 100 }}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Working Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79cupm-39vcws
Hope I was able to help you :)

Comment: Doesn't this just change the animation of the content of the tab? I am trying to change the animation of the tab headers when you click the chevrons in the tab row. It is very slow and it would also be nice if it moved to the next tab instead of a certain number of pixels at a time.

Comment: Okay sorry, then i missunderstood you...
This can easily be achieved with some CSS Code.
Just add 

`:host ::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar { transition: none; }`
into your `tab-group-basic-example.css`